# Distinct values in column for Pivot query

Tags: oracle

I'm currently learning from the book "The Language of SQL" for Oracle environment. One of the PIVOT examples is below:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Channel, State, SalesAmount FROM SalesSummary)
PIVOT (SUM(SalesAmount) FOR State IN ('NY', 'VT'));
```

However, for this easy example, there are only two states in the SalesSummary table. My question is, is there an easy way to list states from an  hypothetical table that contains all 50 states - instead of manual input?

I've tried the following as nested query to no avail:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT Channel, State, SalesAmount FROM SalesSummary)
PIVOT (SUM(SalesAmount) FOR State IN (SELECT DISTINCT(STATE)
FROM SALESSUMMARY));
```

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to list all of the STATES in one column instead of manual input.

Comment: Are you asking, given the 50 known states, how you can save on typing so that you can write the query without too much effort? That can be done. Or are you asking the much harder question - "what if we didn't know what all the states are, until we saw the data at execution time"? That is quite different, it leads you to dynamic SQL, an advanced topic (and a practice that is rarely a good one to boot).

Comment: @mathguy - Hrm. I see what you are saying. Yes to both. 1) Given the 50 known states from another table; or 2) if we didn't know what all the states are, until we saw the data at execution time. Would you be kind to direct me the the dynamic SQL where this topic is covered? I would like to read it as my next learning material.